# Summarizing by group using dplyr not working as expected

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to summarize demographic information of a dataframe and I am running into some issues. Breaking it down by gender, there are 4 possible options that participants can choose from: 1,2,3,4 with blanks (no response) being treated as NA values by R. I am getting the correct counts for each gender but when trying to obtain the mean of each gender is where I am running into issues.

I'd like to keep the observations with NA values because while they may not have answered demographic information, they have answered other questions hence why I do not want to simply remove those rows from the dataframe.

Here is what I tried

```
#df$q10: what is your gender

by_gender = df %>% 
   group_by(df$Q10)  %>% 
   dplyr::summarize(count = n(), 
                    AvgAge = mean(df$Q11_1_TEXT, na.rm = TRUE))

by_gender
```

This returns the same value for all genders as

```
mean(df$Q11_1_TEXT, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Both the gender and age columns have NA values and I suspect this is where the issue may be? I tried adding na.rm = T but that does not seem to work. What else can I try?

Edit: Removing `$` makes the function work as expected.

Comment: It should be `mean(Q11_1_TEXT,..` as `df$` is taking the full dataset

Comment: You should (almost) never be using `$` when you use dplyr.

Comment: That seems to have worked, thanks! What exactly do you mean by "taking the full dataset?" I understand I don't need to specify `df$` since I already passed df at the beginning, I guess I am just curious as to what R is doing when I do pass it again that it is causing the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask for `mean(df$Q11_1_TEXT)` it will calculate a mean from the original ungrouped vector, whereas if you use `mean(Q11_1_TEXT)` it will look for Q11_1_TEXT within the grouped data frame it received from the prior step.

Compare:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarize(wt_ttl = sum(wt), 
            wt_ttl2 = sum(mtcars$wt))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
   gear wt_ttl wt_ttl2
  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     3   58.4    103.
2     4   31.4    103.
3     5   13.2    103.
```